# Fine Uploader failing after server response of 200.

Tags: php, file-upload

I have fine uploader installed via composer to the main site directory of my debian lamp server. The page renders as expected with the file selection and thumbnail rendering of my image file. It gets thru many steps but seems to fail when trying to get the directory contents of the server. I am including the log file below. I am also attempting to run this on my OS X installation but it fails with 403 forbidden when trying to access the folder. Both attempts I am using the default example code provided in the Fine Uploader examples.

Here is the Log:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Parsing template
util.js:236[Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Template parsing complete
util.js:236[Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response.
util.js:236[Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response.
util.js:236[Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Rendering template in DOM.
util.js:236[Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Template rendering complete
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Received 1 files.
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Attempting to validate image.
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Generating new thumbnail for 0
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Attempting to draw client-side image preview.
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Attempting to determine if IMG_2392.jpg can be rendered in this browser
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] First pass: check type attribute of blob object.
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Second pass: check for magic bytes in file header.
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] 'IMG_2392.jpg' is  able to be rendered in this browser
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Moving forward with EXIF header parsing for 'IMG_2392.jpg'
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] EXIF Byte order is big endian
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Found 9 APP1 directory entries
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Successfully parsed some EXIF tags
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Sending simple upload request for 0
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] xhr - server response received for 0
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] responseText = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /server/uploads</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /server/uploads</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th>  

<th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last   modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?  C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/server/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 192.168.1.188 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Received response status 200 with body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /server/uploads</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /server/uploads</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/server/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 192.168.1.188 Port 80</address>
</body></html>

util.js:241 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0)qq.log @ util.js:241log @ uploader.basic.api.js:282(anonymous function) @ util.js:691parseResponse @ traditional.xhr.upload.handler.js:106onUploadOrChunkComplete @ traditional.xhr.upload.handler.js:89xhr.onreadystatechange @ traditional.xhr.upload.handler.js:50
util.js:236 [Fine Uploader 5.11.7] Simple upload request failed for 0
```

Comment: The content that is coming back appears to be from apache's auto index module that creates a file listing when no index page exists. Make sure you are sending the file to the correct location/url.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I am attempting to send the file to /server/uploads. This is the default for the demo. is there a response url that I am missing?